# Dart pub package of the google web components

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, google-web-component

does anyone know if theres a dart version of the google web components? I want to use the google login element

http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-signin/components/google-signin/

does it exist in a dart package or will I need to create my own wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no Dart wrapper currently.

The Dart team is working on making it easier to use JavaScript components generally but beside that I haven't heard of any attempts.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/custom_element_apigen seems to work fine reported someone on a similar question.